# Worklight 6.1 - Host is not responsive. Android login issue

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am getting the below error while trying login to Android device from my locally deployed code. Both the machine & device uses the same WIFI connection(router) . Code is working as expected in the simulator, but not working in the device. I tried some solutions that are provided in the old posts in the forum, but they didn't help!!

[image]

Comment: Can you access that URL from the device's browser?

Comment: Make sure that's the actual server IP address; disable all network cards but 1; check for the IP and make sure that is the one that is used.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Its working now!! I started using WIFI router from the last several days. My Android project was using the old IP that was used by LAN. I changed the new IP in Build and Deploy Target section and ran "Build All Environment" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an IP address issue, where the device is assigned with an IP address that is different from than one assigned to the development server.

Try to disable all network cards but 1 if you have several. Then check for the IP and make sure that is the one that is used for both the server and device.

If you're working against a remote server, verify the correct IP address is used as well.